# Python: Type error anomaly with class arguments

Tags: python, class, import, typeerror

I have a strange issue with one of the classes that I have created in my program called 'criticalPath'. It keeps giving me the `TypeError: criticalPath() takes no arguments` error when it gets imported into a different file and called from it. My other classes don't suffer the same issue. I triple checked the initializations and constructors and I still can't see where the issue is.

Here is the class that has the issue:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import csv
from node import node 
from aon import aon

class criticalPath:
            
    def __init__(self, address):
        
        X = pd.read_csv(address)

        X.drop(X[X['Level'] < 3].index, inplace = True)

        X.drop('Responsible\n(RACI)', axis = 1, inplace = True)

        Dict = {}
        i = 0
        while i < len(X.iloc[:,0]):
            if not self.isfloat(X.iloc[i,3]):
                aloc = X.iloc[i,3].split(", ")      
                Dict[X.iloc[i,1]] = aloc, X.iloc[i,4]
            else:
                Dict[X.iloc[i,1]] = [X.iloc[i,3]], X.iloc[i,4]
            i += 1

        self.raon = aon(Dict)
        self.raon.wbs[0] = self.raon.root


        all_paths = self.DFS(0)
        pl = self.calcPaths(all_paths)

        self.max_len = max(pl[p] for p in pl)
        self.max_paths = [p for p in pl if pl[p] == self.max_len]

    def isfloat(self, num):
        try:
            float(num)
            return True
        except ValueError:
            return False

    def DFS(self, root,seen=None,path=None):
        if seen is None: seen = []
        if path is None: path = [root]

        seen.append(root)

        paths = []
        for t in self.raon.wbs[root].nextN:
            if t not in seen:
                t_path = path + [t]
                paths.append(tuple(t_path))
                paths.extend(self.DFS(t, seen[:], t_path))
        return paths

    def calcPaths(self, paths):
        path_len = {}
        for i in paths:
            pLength = 0
            for j in i:
                pLength = pLength + self.raon.wbs[j].dur
            path_len[i] = pLength
        return path_len

    def displayAon(self):
        node = self.raon.wbs[0]
        queue = deque()
        queue.append(node)
        
        while queue:
            line = []
            while queue:
                line.append(queue.pop())
            for i in line:
                for n in i.nextN:
                    queue.append(self.raon.wbs[n])
                print(i.index, " ", end='')
            print("\n")
```

So whenever I try to call an instance of the criticalPath class it gives me the aforementioned type error.
Full error traceback:

```
In [78]: run test2.py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\Desktop\MSproject\test2.py in <module>
      1 from critical import criticalPath
----> 2 cp = criticalPath("WBS Sample.csv")
      3 print (cp.max_len)
      4
      5

TypeError: criticalPath() takes no arguments
```

NOTE: this is only happening when I import the class to a different file
here is an example call:

```
from critical import criticalPath
cp = criticalPath("WBS Sample.csv")
print (cp.max_len)
```

NOTE: the file that this class is in is called 'critical.py'

I will put the other classes here for reference (these class have no issues):

```
class node:

    def __init__(self, index, depends, dur):
        self.index = index
        self.depends = depends
        self.dur = dur
        self.nextN = []
    
    def __repr__(self):
        return f'node(index={self.index}, depends={self.depends}, duration={self.dur}, next={self.nextN})'
```

```
from node import node
import math 

class aon:
     
    def __init__(self, wbs):
        self.root = node(0, None, 0)
        
        for x in wbs.keys():
            wbs[x] = node(x, wbs[x][0], wbs[x][1])
        for x in wbs.keys():
            if math.isnan(float(wbs[x].depends[0])):
                self.root.nextN.append(wbs[x].index)
            else:
                for i in wbs[x].depends:
                    wbs[float(i)].nextN.append(wbs[x].index)
        self.wbs = wbs
```

Comment: Show the full traceback of the error as properly formatted text in the question.

Comment: You need to check that the correct name is available at the time. Can you add: `print(dir(criticalPath))` just before the line which causes the error? Does it list all the methods which you show above?

Comment: @quamrana I tried your suggestion. And yes it did show all the methods that where in criticalPath.

Comment: But what is `criticalPath`? You said that the class was in `critical.py`? What is `criticalPath` that you import from it?

Comment: @quamrana sorry I need to change that. I changed the file name from `critical.py` to `criticalPath.py` to match the class name in an attempt to fix the problem. but that didn't work.

Comment: I suggest you add: `@classmethod; def cp(cls, address): return criticalPath(address)` to your class and change your calling code to: `cp = criticalPath.cp("WBS Sample.csv")`. This will make sure you are importing the right class.

Comment: @quamrana I tried your suggestion but I got the following error: ```AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
~\Desktop\MSproject\test2.py in <module>
      1 from criticalPath import criticalPath
      2 print(dir(criticalPath))
----> 3 cp = criticalPath.cp("WBS Sample.csv")
      4 print (cp.max_len)
      5

AttributeError: type object 'criticalPath' has no attribute 'cp'```

Comment: Ok, this shows that you are not importing the class you think you are. There must be some other file(s) around with the same name, but which contain a class which does not take parameters.

Comment: @quamrana the file import was not the issue. But I managed to solve the problem by resetting my IPYTHON environment. I think some times the Anaconda IPYTHON hold onto older versions of the code blocks for some reason. Not sure what triggers it. Thank you so much for taking the time to help me.